# Finding nested array objects with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a `user` collection like this

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62fe22f5d37c317701922d66"
  },
  "name": "Fahim Faisal",
  "email": "fahim.faisal.abir@gmail.cc",
  "password": "$2a$12$bkjeD.GesX4f7BNVF7C0CuKkkTyQA19kv6SAWuhObmPlAB11Tz9dy",
  "notes": [],
  "folders": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62fe22f5d37c317701922d67"
      },
      "name": "My Notes",
      "notes": []
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62fe22f5d37c317701922d68"
      },
      "name": "Todos",
      "notes": []
    },
  ],
  "__v": 0
}
```

I want to check if an exact item in `folders` exists or not.

What I have tried so far

```
User.findOne(
    { _id: req.userId },
    {
        folders: {
            $elemMatch: {
                _id,
            },
        },
    },
    (err, system) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(system);
        }
    }
);
```

It doesn't return the exact item. It returns this

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("62faf0c424411076eb9b80e6"),
  folders: [
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("6302110a230f9123c1110273"),
      name: 'My Notes',
      notes: []
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("6302110a230f9123c1110274"),
      name: 'Todos',
      notes: []
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("6302110a230f9123c1110275"),
      name: 'Projects',
      notes: []
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("6302110a230f9123c1110276"),
      name: 'Journals',
      notes: []
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("6302110a230f9123c1110277"),
      name: 'Reading list',
      notes: []
    }
  ]
}
```

What should I do to get the exact item in the `folders` array exists or not?

Comment: Is this [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sagsWyKXImM) meet your requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `$elemMatch` filter for `folders` in the first object parameter, and with [$ (projection)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#mongodb-projection-proj.-) to limit and return the first (matched) item of `folders` array.

Assume that `i_d` is `ObjectId` type.

```js
User.findOne(
    { 
        _id: req.userId,
        folders: {
            $elemMatch: {
                _id: _id
            }
       }
    },
    {
        "folders.$": 1
    },
    (err, system) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(system);
        }
    }
);
```

[Demo @ MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sagsWyKXImM)

Answer (score 0):

You should specify an Id in the `elemMatch`. For example something like this

```
User.findOne(
    { _id: req.userId },
    {
        folders: {
            $elemMatch: {
                _id:ObjectId('String Id'),
            },
        },
    },
    (err, system) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(system);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: As `_id: _id` both are the same, you could just use one.